# Dynamically set JMS selector

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I'm trying to create more than one consumers and each one just receive 1 type of message with some property defined on message:

for example, `message.setProperty("id","someId");`

I'm having now problems on setting selector JmsListener on consumer:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "OMP.DEVICES", containerFactory = "jmsListenerFactory", selector=someVariable)
```

I want to set the selector value dynamically from a variable that I receive..

```
private String someVariable;
public void setsomeVariable(Long id){
        someVariable="Id='"+id+"'";
}
```

But I'm having this error:
`The value for annotation attribute JmsListener.selector must be a constant`

how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The selection string for consumer can't be changed dynamically. Consumer must be closed and reopened with a different selection string.

Comment: but the selection string wouldnt change dynamically on the same consumer.. Basicly I wanted to create a consumer that would have the same selection string on its lifecycle but it would be setted dynamically... Because I didn't find any solutions, I just did a filter that just reads the value if a certain condition is verified